# For which arrangement(s) of known sides and angles in a triangle can the Cosine Rule be used to find an unknown side?

Tags: trigonometry

For which one of the following four triangles may the cosine rule be used to find an unknown side?[image]

## 1

△ABC

## 2

△GHI

## 3

△DEF

## 4

△JKL

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70ivgBBnjnA&index=17&list=PLjnpfDCBCNqRNujUS92H_6rT-sH9mECGg

Answer (score 2):

for 1) we get $$4.1^2=6.4^2+c^2-2\cdot 6.4\cdot c\cdot \cos(38.7^{\circ})$$ here you must solve this equation for $c$
for 3) we have $$12.4^2=9^2+d^2-2\cdot 9\cdot d\cos(135^{\circ})$$
this equation can be solved for $d$ 
for 4) we have:
$$l^2=11^2+6.7^2-2\cdot 11\cdot 6.7\cos(27.6^{\circ})$$

Comment: +1. Of course, in (1) you get ambiguous results, but (3) and (4) provide certainty. The important take-away is that it's incorrect to ask "For which **one** of the following four triangles ...".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** side $a$ must lie opposite the angle $A$

[image]